# ECMAScript function specification

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecma262

(Sorry if it is answered elsewhere)

I was reading ECMAScript 262 Specification (ECMAScript 5th Edition),
and in [4.3.24 on **function**](http://es5.github.io/x4.html#x4.3.24)  it says the following:

> NOTE: In addition to its named properties, a function contains
>   executable code and state that determine how it behaves when invoked.
>   **A functions code may or may not be written in ECMAScript**.

Can someone point out or explain what does it mean that function can be written not in ECMAScript?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Simplest example: If you are trying to show the content of native functions (i.e. functions defined by the specification), you will see something like `function parseInt() { [native code] }`. Such a function is probably directly implemented in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript is a standard that is used in other languages aside from JavaScript such as JScript (Only supported in Internet Explorer, I think?) or ActionScript (Flash).

This statement means you can simply write other syntax in a function other than what is defined in ECMAScript.